# How to use a parcel station in Lithuania to recieve parcel from Germany?

Tags: shipping, lithuania

I will live in Lithuania for two years. Because of some circumstances, like no bell on the gate in fence around the apartments, I want to pick up parcels on a parcel station. Near by there are "Omniva" and "DPD" parcel lockers. 
I explored that "itella" delivers parcel in Lithuania which are started by "Deutsche Post" and DHL from Germany.

What could I do to receive parcels from Germany at Lithuanian pick up station/lockers and what has the parcel sender to write on it?

Comment: DPD has parcel stations and shops in Germany, too.

Comment: @user24582 in real I did think dpd is not for private use, but after your hint I looked, and yes one could send a small package for min. 12,90 to Lithuania.